# How to keep section heading and footnotes on a landscape table

Tags: tables, sectioning, footnotes, page-numbering, landscape

I have a wide table and I'm trying to include both footnotes and the section heading in the same page. Ideally it would also be great to keep the page number in the bottom and not on the side (I included \thispagestyle{empty} to address that.
Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,
    amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,
    graphicx,caption,color,setspace,
    sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,
    pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref, 
    longtable, tabularx, url, lipsum, 
    array, scrlayer, lscape}

\begin{document}

\pagebreak \newpage
\section{Time table} 
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{landscape}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[htbp]
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             & Mar/20 - Aug/20 & Sept/20 - Feb/21 & Mar/21 - Aug/21 & Sept/21 - Feb/22 \footnote{Conditional on XX, I expect YYYYY} &Mar/22 - Aug/22\\
             & Aug/20 & Feb/21 & Aug/21 &  Feb/22 &Aug/22\\\hline
               Course Work and & $\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&&\\
                Summer Schools &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \hline
         Paper 1: & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  &  \\
                 Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
               Paper 1: Data & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$&  &  &  \\
               analysis and writing & & &  &  &  \\
            \hline
               Paper 1: Presenting & &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&\\
               and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
              \hline
            Paper 3: & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  \\
            Data collection &&  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 3: Data &  & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 3: Presenting & &&$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&\\
            and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
            \hline
            Paper 2: &  & $\sqrt{}$ &$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
            Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 2: Data &  &  &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 2: Presenting &  &  &&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$ \\
                           and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
                                  \hline
          Teaching seminar &&&$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
                                              \hline
          Preparation of &&&&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$\\
          final manuscript &&&&&  \\
                                              \hline 
         Dissertation manuscript &&&&& $\sqrt{}$\\
         submission &&&&&  \\
                                                                                            \hline                             
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Project timetable.}
        \label{tab:Project timetable}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{flushleft}



\pagebreak \newpage

\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to keep the footnote in and the section all in the landscaped page?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These solutions use two minipages.  The first spans the entire page, while the second is only as wide as the tabular (which is wider than `\linewidth`).  Adding `\section` also made it too tall.

To fit the footnote text into the smaller minipage I had to use separate `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.  Note that these are not automatically hyperlinked nor use the same format/counter inside a minipage.

This solution prints the section in landscape.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,
    amsfonts,eurosym,ulem,
    graphicx,caption,color,setspace,
    sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,
    pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref, 
    longtable, tabularx, url, lipsum, 
    array, scrlayer}

\begin{document}
Normal page.

\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \dimen0=\oddsidemargin
  \else
    \dimen0=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \noindent\hspace{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\linewidth-\paperheight}% left edge
  \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr \height-1in-\dimen0][0pt]{\rlap{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\paperwidth][c]{\paperheight}% spans entire page
    \def\thefootnote{{\itshape\alph{footnote}}}%
    \sbox0{% measure width of tabular
        \let\thempfn=\thempfootnote
        \small
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             & Mar/20 - Aug/20 & Sept/20 - Feb/21 & Mar/21 - Aug/21 & Sept/21 - Feb/22 \hyperlink{mpfoot.1}{\footnotemark[1]} &Mar/22 - Aug/22\\
             & Aug/20 & Feb/21 & Aug/21 &  Feb/22 &Aug/22\\\hline
               Course Work and & $\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&&\\
                Summer Schools &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \hline
         Paper 1: & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  &  \\
                 Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
               Paper 1: Data & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$&  &  &  \\
               analysis and writing & & &  &  &  \\
            \hline
               Paper 1: Presenting & &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&\\
               and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
              \hline
            Paper 3: & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  \\
            Data collection &&  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 3: Data &  & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 3: Presenting & &&$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&\\
            and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
            \hline
            Paper 2: &  & $\sqrt{}$ &$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
            Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 2: Data &  &  &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 2: Presenting &  &  &&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$ \\
                           and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
                                  \hline
          Teaching seminar &&&$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
                                              \hline
          Preparation of &&&&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$\\
          final manuscript &&&&&  \\
                                              \hline 
         Dissertation manuscript &&&&& $\sqrt{}$\\
         submission &&&&&  \\
         \hline                             
     \end{tabular}}%
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \wd0+\ht1+\dp1}
      \section{Time table}
      \usebox0\raisebox{\ht0}{\rotatebox{-90}{\rlap{\usebox1}}}
      \hypertarget{mpfoot.1}{\footnotetext[1]{Conditional on XX, I expect YYYYY}}
      \captionof{table}{Project timetable.}
      \label{tab:Project timetable}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}}}%\paperheight

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

---

This version rotates the section back into its normal position.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,
    amsfonts,eurosym,ulem,
    graphicx,caption,color,setspace,
    sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,
    pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref, 
    longtable, tabularx, url, lipsum, 
    array, scrlayer}

\begin{document}
Normal page.

\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \dimen0=\oddsidemargin
  \else
    \dimen0=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \dimen1=\textwidth
  \noindent\hspace{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\linewidth-\paperheight}% left edge
  \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr \height-1in-\dimen0][0pt]{\rlap{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\paperwidth][c]{\paperheight}
    \def\thefootnote{{\itshape\alph{footnote}}}%
    \sbox0{% measure width of tabular
        \let\thempfn=\thempfootnote
        \small
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             & Mar/20 - Aug/20 & Sept/20 - Feb/21 & Mar/21 - Aug/21 & Sept/21 - Feb/22 \hyperlink{mpfoot.1}{\footnotemark[1]} &Mar/22 - Aug/22\\
             & Aug/20 & Feb/21 & Aug/21 &  Feb/22 &Aug/22\\\hline
               Course Work and & $\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&&\\
                Summer Schools &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \hline
         Paper 1: & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  &  \\
                 Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
               Paper 1: Data & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$&  &  &  \\
               analysis and writing & & &  &  &  \\
            \hline
               Paper 1: Presenting & &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&&\\
               and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
              \hline
            Paper 3: & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  &  \\
            Data collection &&  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 3: Data &  & $\sqrt{}$ & $\sqrt{}$ &  &  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 3: Presenting & &&$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&\\
            and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
            \hline
            Paper 2: &  & $\sqrt{}$ &$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
            Data collection &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
            Paper 2: Data &  &  &$\sqrt{}$&$\sqrt{}$&  \\
            analysis and writing &  &  &  &  &  \\
                        \hline
            Paper 2: Presenting &  &  &&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$ \\
                           and submission &   &  &  &  &   \\
                                  \hline
          Teaching seminar &&&$\sqrt{}$&&  \\
                                              \hline
          Preparation of &&&&$\sqrt{}$& $\sqrt{}$\\
          final manuscript &&&&&  \\
                                              \hline 
         Dissertation manuscript &&&&& $\sqrt{}$\\
         submission &&&&&  \\
         \hline                             
       \end{tabular}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\dimen1}{\section{Time table}}}%
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \wd0+\ht1+\dp1}
      \usebox0\raisebox{\ht0}{\rotatebox{-90}{\rlap{\usebox1}}}
      \hypertarget{mpfoot.1}{\footnotetext[1]{Conditional on XX, I expect YYYYY}}
      \captionof{table}{Project timetable.}
      \label{tab:Project timetable}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}}}%\paperheight

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunatelly, none of them really works. In the first solution because in both of them I still have the section head in a different page than the table and in the second one the table goes out of the page margins. But thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You could move the \section inside the landscape environment.  I just thought that would make it hard to find.